# Twitter APIs - Twitter4j - sync issue?

Tags: authentication, synchronization, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4J to retrieve user timelines, but it stopped working. The number of accepted requests is fine, but I get a autentication problem, probably related to clock sync?

INFO: Error while querying Twitter: 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the **system clock is in sync**.
{"request":"/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json","error":"Not authorized."}

401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
{"request":"/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json","error":"Not authorized."}

*rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{**remaining=178**, limit=180, resetTimeInSeconds=1432305852, secondsUntilReset=899}, version=3.0.5}*

Not sure what to do then. ive tried already to sync my server with ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using SandBox(Build-in VM) of Cloudera/Hortonworks etc

I was also getting the same problem and was trying to sync my clock with 'time.windows.com' clock but I was failed to do. So I moved to 4 nodes cluster which was already existing in my case and there my clock was in sync and I could run my request to Twitter successfully.

Conclusion: Move from Cloudera/Hortonworks VM to own installed OS and make the clock sync.

Hope this help!!!